# VBScript: изменение условия скачивания

Tags: vbscript

Здравствуйте. Для скачивания файлов иногда использую скрипт-CMD, запускающий `wget` и работающий в связке с `scriptsplit.vbs`. Программа скачивает список ссылок из файла lst.txt — в новый файл со случайным именем, по достижении квоты в 399мб — создавая и наполняя новый файл.

Файл "start.cmd"

```
"G:\_wget\wget.exe" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0 SeaMonkey/2.23" --header="Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en;q=0.8" --wait=1 --rejected-log=_ERROR.LOG -i lst.txt -O- | cscript scriptsplit.vbs
```

Файл "scriptsplit.vbs"

```
SplitSize = 399 * 1024 * 1024 
 Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
 Set stdin = fso.GetStandardStream(0) 
 Count = 0 
 Set CurrFile = FSO.CreateTextFile("lst" & CStr(Year(Date())) & "-" & Right("0" & CStr(Month(Date())), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & CStr(Day(Date())), 2) & "_" & Replace(Time,":","-") & Count & ".htm",1) 
 Do Until stdin.AtEndOfStream 
   CurrFile.Write stdin.Read(1024) 
   Size = Size + 1024 
   If (Size => SplitSize) Then  
     Count = Count + 1 
     CurrFile.Close 
     Set CurrFile = FSO.CreateTextFile("lst" & CStr(Year(Date())) & "-" & Right("0" & CStr(Month(Date())), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & CStr(Day(Date())), 2) & "_" & Replace(Time,":","-") & Count & ".htm",1) 
     Size = 0 : Data = "" 
   End If 
 Loop 
 CurrFile.Close
```

Вопрос заключается в возможности изменения условия скачивания: этой функции квоты — на скачанное количество ссылок, чтобы новый файл создавался не в зависимости от размера файла, а в зависимости от числа скачанных ссылок. Потому что иначе HTML-файлы перед последующей обработкой приходится объединять, поскольку они разрываются в случайном месте, помимо того, что иногда кодировка файлов портится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения поставленной задачи придётся не сразу записывать прочитанную порцию в выходной файл, а помещать её в переменную, после чего выделять из переменной ссылки по одной и отправлять в файл назначения. Когда останется одна ссылка - подчитывать в переменную следующую порцию. При достижении установленного количества ссылок - формировать новый файл.

Навскидку это будет, например, так:

```
Const ReferencesCount = 1000000 ' ссылок на файл '
Dim Buffer ' буфер приёма и парсинга ссылок '
Dim NextRef ' буфер под выделение ссылки '
Dim RefCount ' количество ссылок, записанных в файл '
Dim FSO,stdin,Count,CurrFile ' переменные из исходного кода '

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set stdin = FSO.GetStandardStream(0) 
Count = 0 
Set CurrFile = FSO.CreateTextFile("lst" & CStr(Year(Date())) & "-" & Right("0" & CStr(Month(Date())), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & CStr(Day(Date())), 2) & "_" & Replace(Time,":","-") & Count & ".htm",1) 
Do Until stdin.AtEndOfStream 
    Buffer = Buffer & stdin.Read(1024)
    NextRef = ExtractRef(Buffer)
    Do Until NextRef = ""
        CurrFile.Write NextRef & vbNewLine ' по одной ссылке на строку '
        RefCount = RefCount + 1
        If RefCount>= ReferencesCount Then
            CurrFile.Close
            Count = Count + 1
            Set CurrFile = FSO.CreateTextFile("lst" & CStr(Year(Date())) & "-" & Right("0" & CStr(Month(Date())), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & CStr(Day(Date())), 2) & "_" & Replace(Time,":","-") & Count & ".htm",1) 
            RefCount = 0
        End If
        NextRef = ExtractRef(Buffer)
    Loop
Loop 
CurrFile.Close

Function ExtractRef(ByRef Buffer)
Dim Border ' Граница первой ссылки в буфере '

Buffer = Trim(Buffer)
Border = Instr(Buffer, " ") ' если разделитель ссылок - пробел '
If Border = 0 Then 
    ExtractRef = ""
Else
    ExtractRef = Trim(Left(Buffer, Border))
    Buffer = Mid(Buffer, Border)
End If
End Function
```

Comment: У меня почему-то скачивание не происходит — создаётся файл с нулевым размером. Также, при скачивании тестовых десяти ссылок, уменьшил число ссылок на файл до трёх — всё равно файлы не появляются. Сейчас подумалось: в плане производительности не было бы эффективней и проще считать не ссылки — а время с момента создания активного файла? Чтобы запоминалось время, когда текущий наполняемый файл был создан — и если с момента его создания прошло больше трёх часов — создавался бы новый файл?

Comment: *У меня почему-то скачивание не происходит* Этот процесс находится за пределами данного скрипта. Но на всякий случай проверил скрипт, уменьшив количество ссылок на порцию и заменив чтение из потока на открытие локального файла - всё выполняется как задумано.

Comment: Аа-а, спасибо. При вставке кода в файл "scriptsplit.vbs", надо ли делать в нём какие-то изменения? Потому что пока что скрипт находится за пределами практического применения мной))

Comment: *надо ли делать в нём какие-то изменения?* Да вроде бы нет, если исходный скрипт был полностью рабочим в заданном окружении... разве что значение ReferencesCount поменять на нужное и разделитель ссылок в функции подрихтовать.